# Having Duplicate and included Index in Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, indexing, query-optimization

Database having multiple tables and those tables are having duplicate, overlapping, included index. Where some of the index (like duplicate) are idle and not used by the query plans.

So if I plan to remove those index from a DB, will that give good performance, improve speed or will that give any bad impact?

For example: I have 2 tables and created different indexes and used SQL query to find those indexes from the table.

This is the output:

[image]

I need your opinion to remove unused index and Is there any steps to follow before removing those index.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If indexes are completely redundant (index type, key columns, included columns, and filter predicates), it is generally safe to remove the duplicates. The exception is if the index is referenced by query hints.

Note the query results in your screenshot does not include the index type (clustered, nonclustered, columnstore, filter).